# Problem on validating radio button in template driven forms

Tags: angular, forms

I have a dynamic form that creates many radio button groups. The choises are yes, no or not applicable I would like to show required error if the user does not select radio button. This is the code that generates radio buttons.

```
            <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <div class="flex-grow-1">
                    <span>{{i + 1}}</span>
                    {{item.question.question}}
                  </div>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let radio of yesNoValues; let j = index">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input"
                               type="radio"
                               [name]="radio.name + i"
                               [id]="'inlineRadio' + j"
                               [value]="radio.id"
                               [(ngModel)]="item.result"
                               #{{radio.name}}{{i}}="ngModel"
                               [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && radio.name + i + '.invalid' }" required>
                        <label class="form-check-label" [for]="'inlineRadio' + j">{{radio.name}}</label>
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="f.submitted && radio.name + i + '.invalid'" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="radio.name + i + '.errors.required'">Required field</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ng-container>
                  <div>
                    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-light text-dark">{{item.question.point}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

This is the result;

[image]

As you can see even if I selected the radio it shows required error.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by giving static template id instead of dynamic one. That is '#myRadio'. So the correct form is;

```
<div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div class="flex-grow-1">
                <span>{{i + 1}}</span>
                {{item.question.question}}
              </div>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let radio of yesNoValues; let j = index">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input"
                           type="radio"
                           [name]="radio.name + i"
                           [id]="'inlineRadio' + j"
                           [value]="radio.id"
                           [(ngModel)]="item.result"
                           #myRadio="ngModel"
                           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && myRadio.invalid }" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" [for]="'inlineRadio' + j">{{radio.name}}</label>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && radio.name + i + '.invalid'" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="myRadio.errors.required">Required field</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
              <div>
                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-light text-dark">{{item.question.point}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```